# Sentry - Celery can't save to DB - SAVEPOINT does not exist

Tags: mysql, django, celery, sentry, raven

My Sentry instance stopped working.

I can send data to sentry with raven but celery doesn't save exception to database. I see `DatabaseError`:

```
DatabaseError: (1305, 'SAVEPOINT s140249944147776_x1 does not exist')
```

Savepoint name is different for every call.

I tried to release savepoint using dbshell:

```
mysql> RELEASE SAVEPOINT s140249944147776_x1;
ERROR 1305 (42000): SAVEPOINT s140249944147776_x1 does not exist
```

Any suggestions?